# count down timer reset issue

Tags: javascript, setinterval

When I am moving to the next question, the timer starts from the start - meaning that, when I have started taking exam *n* I have set my timer to 5 minutes but when I am moving to the next question the timer starts from 5 minutes for each *n* every question). I want to set the timer for my whole quiz the same when I start the quiz and it doesn't reset to each and every question for new time (i.e. 5 minutes).

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var start = Date.now(),
        diff,
        minutes,
        seconds;
    function timer() {
        // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since 
        // startTimer() was called
        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

        // does the same job as parseInt truncates the float
        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds; 

        if (diff <= 0) {
            // add one second so that the count down starts at the full duration
            // example 05:00 not 04:59
            start = Date.now() + 1000;
        }
    };
    // we don't want to wait a full second before the timer starts
    timer();
    setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
<body>
    <div>Registration closes in <span id="time"></span> minutes!</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why does this have `servlets` tag, and not `javascript`?

Comment: sry it will be javascript tag

Comment: sry ,the tag will be javascript

Comment: Jozef can u help me regarding this problem because i am facing problem for that reason i cant move forward

Comment: What is an `exam n`? Is the time supposed to reset based on user interaction (e.g. clicking a button, to move to a new question)? if so, please update the example (and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 0):

> "When I am moving to the next question"

How're you moving to the next question? full page load?

You have a `window.onload` event which will reset the timer if the window is reloaded... is the window being reloaded upon moving to the next question?

The question needs some more information.